# Are there an infinite and finite amount of numbers between 0 and 1?

Tags: infinity

I saw an exchange on twitter recently, and am wondering if someone can clear this up. Are there an infinite and finite amount of numbers between 0 and 1? I thought there is an infinite amount between two numbers. I'm confused with what the person below means by `Infinite, and yet finite. Since the number 1 exists`

person a:

```
   1 + 1 = 2 true?
```

person b:

```
   1 + 1 does not equal 2, for some large values of 1
```

person a:

```
   there are a lot of decimals points/numbers between 0 and 1
```

person b:

```
   not just a lot. Infinite
```

person a:

```
   Infinite, and yet finite. Since the number 1 exists
```

Comment: Is there a mathematical question here?

Comment: I personally think it's trolling... or it could be `person a` doesn't know much about mathematics and genuinely believes there is a finite number of numbers between 0 and 1

Comment: I think there is confusion about infinite *cardinality* and numbers being bounded

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, the question was is there both an infinite and finite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, and if so what 1 existing would have to do with that. I don't have a background in math so I probably didn't ask the question well.

Comment: @mdave16 I don't/didn't believe, I heard someone say there was, and that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinite numbers between 0 and 1.

$0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, ....$

Just between 0 and .1 there is infinite numbers.